# QTreeView Display Directory

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently trying to make a QTreeView to display the contents of the folder on the computer. However, I experienced some weird issue where . and .. are displayed in the tree view which I do not want that to happen. How am I suppose to disable showing . and .. in the tree view?

[image]

Here is the code for the QTreeView.

```
model = new QDirModel(this);
model->setReadOnly(true);
model->setSorting(QDir::DirsFirst | QDir::IgnoreCase | QDir::Name);
model->setFilter(QDir::Dirs);

ui->treeView->setModel(model);

// expand to D: Directory
QModelIndex index = model->index("D:/");
ui->treeView->expand(index);
ui->treeView->scrollTo(index);
ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(index);
ui->treeView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
```

Comment: Add flag QDir::NoDotAndDotDot in setFilter...

Comment: I added QDir::NoDotAndDotDot but I can longer expand the folder anymore

Comment: it seems two setFilter line will not work, but instead use setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir:Dirs) works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figure out the answer:

```
model->setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

Using the following will not work as the tree view can longer be expanded on each folder:

```
model->setFilter(QDir::Dirs);
model->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

Comment: That's because the second `setFilter` replaces the first.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I wasn't knewing that.

Answer (score 0):

You had a look at this?
This is a standard Qt example given out with Qt creator, They are doing exact same what you want to do.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QFileSystemModel model;
        model.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );
        model.setRootPath("");
        QTreeView tree;
        tree.setModel(&model);

        // Demonstrating look and feel features
        tree.setAnimated(false);
        tree.setIndentation(20);
        tree.setSortingEnabled(true);

        tree.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Dir View"));
    #if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN) || defined(Q_WS_MAEMO_5)
        tree.showMaximized();
    #else
        tree.resize(640, 480);
        tree.show();
    #endif

        return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at this before, as I am using QtCreator for the interface, some part of code doesn't works well for me, but anyway, I got the problem sort out a couple of minutes ago

Comment: I am also using QtCreator and this code was supposed to work as is, since it was an example code supplied with Qt. I really wonder why it does not.